# Getting error when make ipa for Apple Watch

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-watch, provisioning-profile, code-signing-certificate

How to make ipa for Apple Watch? I use [Reference for making ipa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29272260/3378413)

In solution tell me that there are 6 provisioning profiles required for making ipa. But my question is how to use these 6 provisioning profiles?

I am using 3 provisioning profiles :
1) for Project Target.
2) for WatchKit Extension.
3) for WatchKit App.

There is an error when I use this scenario.

> (null): error: Embedded binary's bundle identifier is not prefixed
>   with the parent app's bundle identifier.

What is wrong with me? Please any one solve my Query Because I already take two much time for making ipa for apple watch and iPhone Integration.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30210346/4151918

Answer (score 0):

In your Xcode project, check that all your targets has the same bundle identifier's prefix.

For exemple:

- com.mycompany.myapp
- com.mycompany.myapp.watchkitapp
- com.mycompany.myapp.watchkitapp.watchkitextension