# Xcode 8.0 Failed to load GameScene.sks after renaming the app (Swift)

Tags: swift3, xcode8, ios10

I renamed my perfectly runnig app. Big mistake ;-) I followed [Bundle IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203079/watchkit-extension-bundle-identifiers)  after running into difficulties with the bundle identifier, which now work just fine. Nevertheless I seem to miss something. When I build the app I get "Failed to load GameScene.sks" The simulation crashes after showing the launcher. Any ideas?

(Since I am new to this I've got no clue in wich part of my code you might be interested at this point. Please aks for it specificaly. Thank you.)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I rename the GameScene file and now getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your product name doesn't contain any ambiguous characters, such as an *en dash* (`–`).

I've just encountered this error, but when I replaced the `–` in the product name with a hyphen (`-`), it worked again.