# App not installing on Apple Watch

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I am working on sample watch kit app (Apple Watch + iPhone). My app present in the device syncing to Apple Watch is working fine. And I enable the Show App on Apple Watch option. After that my app started installing in Apple Watch but it is automatically stopped after a few seconds.

I refered these link using creating bundle identifiers.
[WatchKit Extension bundle identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203079/watchkit-extension-bundle-identifiers)

Please help me ...

Comment: there is nothing called iWatch.

Comment: write your crash log

Comment: I guess you are talking about Apple Watch or watch?

Comment: @Raptor , i think this is rather obvious what does he mean.

Comment: Yes. I’m talking about the Apple Watch.

Comment: @Raptor What did u mean??

Comment: Here is my error: Error Domain=ACXErrorDomain Code=17 "Got error 17 in install done from remote side (MI error DeviceOSVersionTooLow ;Extended 0x0 ; Desc The system version is lower than the minimum OS version specified for bundle at /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.daOrin/extracted/Payload/iwatch.app. Have 2.1; need 2.2)" UserInfo={SourceFileLine=524, NSLocalizedDescription=Got error 17 in install done from remote side (MI error DeviceOSVersionTooLow ; Extended 0x0 ; Desc The system version is lower than the minimum OS version specified for bundle

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below process. And it is worked for me.

I am creating watch kit extension in XCode6.4 version. then it is running on physical device.

You have to be careful when changing the bundle identifiers, here's how they should be set (you need can change each identifier in the Info.plist for the iPhone app, for the Watchkit Extension and for the Watchkit App).

However i created in Info.plist and my bundle identifier is

com.myname.myappname
and my bundle identifier of my WatchKit extension is

com.myname.myappname.extension