# Independent Watch app in a different bundle

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, watchkit, apple-watch

So, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203079/watchkit-extension-bundle-identifiers) this should be the bundle ids of my app:

- iPhone app: `com.fruitcompany.orange`
- Watchkit app: `com.fruitcompany.orange.watchkit`
- Watchkit extension: `com.fruitcompany.orange.watchkit.extension`

and then I just have to set the `WKCompanionAppBundleIdentifier` of the Watchkit app to `com.fruitcompany.orange` to the watch app is linked to its companion app.

That's fine.

My problem is the iPhone version was done in Xamarin. And for the Watch we are developing it natively in Xcode. To create this project I followed [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/creating_independent_watchos_apps) instructions. The WatchKit app and Extension are wrapped in a stub application that's only used to be able to upload the app to AppStore Connect.

But this stub app needs its own bundle id, and the WatchKit app and Extension bundle ids need to be derived from it (as far as I understand)

So if the stub's bundle id is: `com.fruitcompany.orange.watchwrapper` then the WatchKit app needs to be `com.fruitcompany.orange.watchwrapper.watchkit` and the extension `com.fruitcompany.orange.watchwrapper.watchkit.extension`.

The problem with this is, if I set `WKCompanionAppBundleIdentifier` to be `com.fruitcompany.orange` (the Xamarin app), App Store Connect complains it's not correct, because it should be `com.fruitcompany.orange.watchwrapper` the empty wrapper app.

I'm trying to communicate between my watch app and my iPhone app using the Watch Connectivity framework, and for that I, apparently, the iPhone app needs to be set and the watch app companion.

Is there a solution for this or am I out of luck? Is there a workaround? My main purpose for now is being able to share sign in credentials.

Comment: You will need to bring the Xamarin binary and the watch app binary together into the same bundle so that you can deliver a single bundle containing the WatchKit app and the companion app. I don't use xamarin so I can't tell you the exact steps required, but it should be possible. The app bundle is basically just a zip file.

Comment: This answer seems to go along those lines. It looks painful though... and also a challenge to do it in the CI server. https://xamarin.github.io/bugzilla-archives/43/43985/bug.html#c12

Comment: Yep, that was the sort of process I was thinking of.