# Signed with same certificate but error: Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate

Tags: ios, apple-watch

The embedded binary and the parent app has the same certificate but I am getting the error message: ***error: Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate as the parent app. Verify the embedded binary target's code sign settings match the parent app's.***

[image]

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 6 error: "Embedded binary's bundle identifier is not prefixed with the parent app's bundle identifier."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045417/xcode-6-error-embedded-binarys-bundle-identifier-is-not-prefixed-with-the-par)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just Xcode making you go crazy,all what you have to do is

1. Go to the `Preferences->Accounts` (Command+,)
2. Remove the AppleID which is causing the problem
3. Sign in again with the same AppleID

Enjoy :D

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few reasons the issue may emanate from. Would like to add another plausible check that helped me. *Ensure the certificate you are signing with doesn't have 'Always Trust'* (you will see a green '+' sign if the setting is such).

1. Go to Key Chain access, double click on the certificate you are using.
2. Expand the 'Trust' drop down and change/set to '**Use System Defaults**' from 'Always Trust'.

It's especially true if you are using Swift in your project as the 'Always Trust' setting breaks pertinent Swift libraries.

Comment: Putting "Use System Defaults" instead of "Always Trust" has worked for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm glad that it helped someone! I know how frustrating the ordeal can get! :)

Answer (score 1):

1) You have to go on the developer.apple.com portal

2) declare two new app IDs, com.organisation.appname.watchkitextension
and one with com.organisation.appname.watchapp

3)then add two new Provisioning profiles for this two app Ids..

**Warning ! : you have to select the same certificate that the parent App, if you have a doubt, i recommend you to re-create this certificate...**

4) in build settings, for all targets you have to spot the correct profile...

Hope that's helping.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, I don't understand why but it worked for 2 keyboard extensions:

Go to Build Setting

1. set project code signing to distribution
2. set target wrapper code signing  to developer
3. set extension to code signing  developer

I tried a lot of suggestions, including new profiles, new certs, new App ID, clean build, delete derived data, restart, reset, etc etc, but this was the only one that worked for me, even though it the code signing of the parent and embed app is definitely not the same.

Comment: Thank you. Just thank you. P.S. Mine didn't work until I changed it back to developer but this fixed it