# Watchkit app upload issues using xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, watchkit, watchos-2, xcode7.3

I am not able to submit my build which supports watchkit extension using xcode7.3....I recieved following error mail from itunesconnect ...

> "We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "xxx Mobile". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:
>
> 1) Invalid WatchKit Support - The WatchKitSupport2 folder is missing. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it.
>
> 2) Invalid Executable - The executable'***.app/Watch/watchkitapp.app/PlugIns/watchkitapp Extension.appex/watchkitapp Extension' does not contain bitcode."

I am having few questions regarding submitting native apps to itunesconnect

1) In order to submit update for existing apps with watchkit extension (watchos1.0) do we need to remove our existing watchkit extension & add new seperate watchos2 target?

2) My present watchkit extension is having bundle ID as "AppBundleId.watchkitextension" which is used as provisioning profile as well...But now we have to change bunde ID to "AppleBundleId.watchkitapp.watchkitextension"..do we need to change bundle Id in our provisioning profile as well  & regenerate it again?

Comment: look  at my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39835420/navigationbar-delay-updating-bartintcolor-ios10/40255483#40255483

Comment: If you have problem with navBar delay issue...please comment on my answer not the original post...this makes confusion with the question owner and myself.....keep in mind.

Comment: Ok.can you post an another question with your problem because I can't go back to your profile every time if i need to comment .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. According to apple, it should be possible to ship both 1.0 and 2.0 extensions in your app.  Some people have reported trouble doing this however. If I were you I would just go to 2.0, as it's so much better, most watch users have probably already upgraded.
2. Yes, you will need matching provisioning profiles.

Comment: i was able to upload my app to itunesconnect by changing provisioning profile to automatic in watchkit extension & watch app build settings as suggested in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045417/xcode-6-error-embedded-binarys-bundle-identifier-is-not-prefixed-with-the-par/32876403#comment63634743_32876403...  But I guess submitting app by not providing new provisioning profile with modified bundle id provide might lead to rejection of app...

Comment: If automatic works for you, then it should be OK with apple.  It's how it's supposed to work, but it sometimes doesn't.