# NavigationBar delay updating barTintColor iOS10

Tags: objective-c, swift, uinavigationbar, ios10

**Context:**

Let's say we have one `NavigationController` and 2 viewControllers. 
`ViewControllerA` has a blue navigationBar, while `ViewControllerB` has a green one.

I set them up like so :

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blue    // Green if ViewController B
    }
```

It works well when I got from A to B, but when I return, the navigationBar teint is updated after. Like if it was set up in the `viewDidAppear`.

**Expected:**

The navigation bar should have its navigation bar color updated without delay.

**Solutions tried:**

- I've seen this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39511088/navigationbar-coloring-in-viewwillappear-happens-too-late-in-ios-10) post, and I tried the solution. It worked, but would make the management of the navigation bar a lot more complex and painful. (in a real app)
- I've tried to change the navbar teint in the `ViewWillDisappear` method. Didn't work.

**More:**

This is caused by a change on the ios10 API. I've read the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-10.0/index.html), but it's still unclear what should be done in this case.

> In iOS 10, UIKit has updated and unified background management for
>   UINavigationBar, UITabBar, and UIToolbar. In particular, changes to
>   background properties of these views (such as background or shadow
>   images, or setting the bar style) may kick off a layout pass for the
>   bar to resolve the new background appearance.
>
> In particular, this
>   means that attempts to change the background appearance of these bars
>   inside of layoutSubviews, -[UIView updateConstraints],
>   viewWillLayoutSubviews, viewDidLayoutSubviews, updateViewConstraints,
>   or any other method that is called in response to layout may result in
>   a layout loop.
>
> In some cases you can break these layout loops by ensuring that you
>   always use the same object instance when objects (such as UIImage or
>   UIColor) are required. But in general you should avoid doing this.

**Question:**

What would be the best way to handle the navigation bar changes between different navigation controllers in iOS 10 ?

Comment: have you found the solution.

Comment: @Joe I ended up using the solution linked in my post. Still, I believe it'll make management of the navbar more complicated

Comment: I have done a test project similar to your problem.In that project, I have a 3vc connected with no segue and have a different navigation bar and status bar colour. I don't see any delay on navBar colour while transition.let me know is this the answer you after...

Comment: @Joe, are you using a `navigationController` or not ? Because I made a test project (as described in the question), and I could reproduce the same thing. But using segues ..

Comment: Yes,To achieve this.you have to tweak the navigationBar settings and programmically put the status bar...I will try to upload the project in GitHub sometime today....

Comment: @joe hv u posted any solution for this issue?

Comment: @jayantrawat As mentioned in the question, I used this solution : http://stackoverflow.com/a/39518148/4013333

Comment: @tsnkff i am using tab bar controller & there are no specific methods for push or pop to view controllers as given in solution..

Comment: sorry buddy. i forgot about all... can you update ur post with storyboard screenshot and we start all over again...thanks

Comment: r you using segue to connect your second VC...let me know r u passing any  data between controller..

Comment: i am trying to achieve using smile tweak. but, i am getting the same delay issue. i can update my answer.but, you won't probably understand..if you wish i can update my test project.you may be check my answer in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176803/swift-navigation-bar-background-color-white-does-not-work/40178657#40178657 if you like the post give me a up vote ..cheers

Comment: @ joe i am using [ [self.navigationController pushViewController:@"vc2"animated:YES];. while navigating to 2nd view controller i am not getting delay issue but while coming back from 2nd view controller i am getting delay issue...

Comment: I found the solution for your problem.still you looking for the answer. let me know...

Comment: @joe i am still looking for solution...it will be helpful if u tell me actual solution..

Comment: Did you look at my answer...

Comment: i looked into it but it is not working for me..i am setting navigation bar color as    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PlainTabbarOS7@2x.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]... i am not setting tint color as u hv mentioned..

Comment: You can Set your image inside your tincolor using pattern image....still my code fix ur problem.let me know.i will update my code

Comment: check my update

Comment: @joe it does not fix my problem

Comment: What you mean.did you tried my answer.tell me what problem are you facing now

Comment: I am still confused this post originally posted by tsnkff.did you upvote my answer?.how do you want me to help you.

Comment: @Joe I told you I ended up using the solution linked. You provided me a thoroughly written answer, which I couldn't test so I upvoted it. If I had tested, I would have accepted the answer instead.

Comment: Sorry man I thought. I am talking to a another guy...

Answer (score 14):

Try this code:

**Note:** Code Tested in Swift 3.

In ViewController A:

```
    override var isViewLoaded: Bool {
    title = "View 1"
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .blue
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white]
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black // In case statusbar Light content wont work.
    return true
    }
```

In ViewController B:

```
    override var isViewLoaded: Bool {
    title = "View 2"
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .green
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white]
    return true
    }
```

**Output:** No delay what so ever...

[image]

**Pattern Image as a TintColor.**

In ViewController A:

```
 navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "viewOneImage.jpg")!)
```

In ViewController B:

```
 navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "viewTwoImage.jpg")!)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: it does not fix my problem..i am still getting delay while navigating back to previous view controller...

Comment: You might be having two different navigationControllers.

Comment: Thanks it works! Don't forget about super.isViewLoaded

Comment: It works, but at the end return super.isViewLoaded otherwise the app will crash

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't happy with the solution overriding `isViewLoaded` because if there's ever a time `view_controller_a` is shown and you use the value of `view_controller_b.isViewLoaded` for whatever reason, then you'll end up changing the nav bar to the wrong display.

Instead, I would store the nav bar configuration you want in each view controller and use `UINavigationControllerDelegate`:

```
class NavBarConfig
{
    var background_color: UIColor

    init( background_color: UIColor )
    {
        self.background_color = background_color
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    var nav_bar_config: NavBarConfig?
}

class NavControllerDelegate: UINavigationControllerDelegate
{
    //Called just before the navigation controller displays a view controller’s view and navigation item properties.
    func navigationController( _ nav_controller: UINavigationController, willShow view_controller: UIViewController, animated: Bool )
    {
        if let view_controller = view_controller as? ViewController, let nar_bar_config = view_controller.nav_bar_config
        {
            nav_controller.navigationBar.barTintColor = view_controller.nar_bar_config.background_color
        }
    }
}
```

After setting the delegate on your nav controller,  `your_nav_controller.delegate = NavControllerDelegate()`, the delegate method will be called just before each view controller is displayed allowing you to configure the nav bar how you wish.