# Swift - how to remove black navigation bar when navigate between 2 view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

My apps is currently contains the 2 UIViewController VC1 to VC2.

In VC1 is the home screen and has an orange gradient image on `UINavigationBar`

In VC2 has a translucent `UINavigationBar` and set UIImage on `UINavigationBar`

but when navigation between this two view controllers, it appears a black navigation bar until the transition have done. I have try to set `setNavigationBarHidden` but I do not want hide the navigation bar, so how can I remove the black navigation bar?

**Like this-**

[image: navigation from VC1 to VC2]

In VC1

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {        
    if let navController = self.navigationController {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gradientLayer.frame.size)
        gradientLayer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
            navController.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, forBarMetrics: .Default)
            navController.navigationBar.translucent = false
        })
    }
}
```

in VC2

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) { 
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
        })
}


override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {        
    if let navController = self.navigationController {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gradientLayer.frame.size)
        gradientLayer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
            navController.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, forBarMetrics: .Default)
            navController.navigationBar.translucent = false
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39835420/navigationbar-delay-updating-bartintcolor-ios10/40255483#40255483

Answer (score 9):

If you want to hide navigation bar without black color in transition.
(It's in second screen)

Swift4:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)  
  }
```

Comment: Please be some more Specific To give Ans

Comment: Thanks man! It worked. I used `isHidden` property of navigation bar that's not worked.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5 Simple way

```
//MARK:- Only use this code where you want to hide the navigation bar 
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the `NavigationBar` color directly with e.g.: `navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = .orange`

Comment: i have set back the color for the nav bar in viewWillDisappear but still not working...

Comment: perhaps post your code so we can see better whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are setting the color of your `Navigation Bar`. If you set it in the next view's `viewDidLoad` then when you press a button for the transition it will change before the view pushes the next controller.

What timing do you want it to change at?

For Before:
`viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`

For After:
`viewDidAppear`

And make sure you aren't setting it or the imageView on `viewWillDisappear` so it won't be black.

Comment: I put in this way: In VC1, viewWillAppear set orange gradient nav bar. If move to VC2, viewWillAppear(VC2) set image to nav bar and when press back button, viewWillDisappear set the nav bar to orange gradient.

Answer (score 0):

Obj C:

```
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true;
```

Swift:

```
extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
```