# UIView segue UINavigationBar flicker

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm segueing from one view to another using `performSegue(withIdentifier: "showActivities", sender: nil)`
The segue works fine but the black navigation bar flickers before it gets totally black. I'm doing the same between to other views and everything works fine.
The image shows what I mean.
Can anybody help me?

[image: Navigationbar flickers]
[image: Gif Flicker]

Comment: Think you could put a gif up of the problem?

Comment: I added the gif

Comment: I added a toolbar to the bottom, this is also flickering like the navigation bar...

Comment: is this what you looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39835420/navigationbar-delay-updating-bartintcolor-ios10/40255483#40255483

Answer (score -1):

This heppend because nav bar have bugged animation, u need to set view under navbar to dark color.