# I want the two Navigationbar of controller show different colors when Interaction

Tags: ios, navigationbar, interaction, navigationcontroller

when i use NavigationController gesture to push or pop controller, I want to the two Navigationbar of controller show different colors. but i found The two pages will share one Navigationbar. How to solve this problem?

Comment: You can customize navigation header color (or use image ) in each class, where you want to show different colors navigation Bar.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39835420/navigationbar-delay-updating-bartintcolor-ios10/40255483#40255483