# iOS Swift Transition from normal navigation bar to transparent bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, transition

[image]

I googled for similar issues, but none of them actually solves this.
I tried to push from a view controller with normal navigation bar, to a new view controller with transparent navigation bar.
This is the code in 2nd view controller that I used to set navigation bar transparent

`self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .clear
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true`

How can I get a smooth transition without having a piece of light gray on navigation bar during transition?

Comment: Where did you added the code to make it transparent? in `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear`?

Comment: I set it in viewDidLoad, no matter where I set, this still happens

Comment: did you try to add it in viewDidAppear?

Comment: This post may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44343355/3900902

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to create a custom navigation bar and use it instead. It will look much better. I have had similar issues and the only thing that solved it for me was to create the custom navigation bar. Go to your Storyboard and add it:

[image]

Comment: Where should I set this navigation bar? on 1st or 2nd view? what else should I do or just it?

Comment: I would use it everywhere, but if you only want you could just set it on the 2nd view.

Comment: I don't really know what to do with this

Comment: @HoangTrung, I created a custom project that shows how you can do this. You can download it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ixjxcjifvuo6vna/CustomNavigationBar.zip?dl=0).

Comment: thanks for the sample code. I tried to set transparent bar for 2nd VC, It's working nicely when push, but when going back, the back button is not moving as expected

Comment: Did you try my sample project? It solves your issue.

Comment: yes i did. It's working nicely when push, but when going back, the back button is not moving as expected

Comment: It´s a default behaviour, you can try to gide the navbar in your viewWillDisappear in VC2 and see if you think it´s better.

Comment: anyway, this should be easiest way to deal with this issue. Thanks

Comment: @HoangTrung, np glad to help. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm attaching a sample project for your reference, everything is setup via storyboard, no code. Hope it helps!

[file link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=61138477982646338706)

*Here's what the project achieves, on the viewController showing the button, the navigation bar is visible, and when the button is clicked, another viewController is pushed into view, but the navigation bar is hidden completely from view. It only appears when the user taps anywhere within the view.*

Comment: @HoangTrung please check now. there was a typo. My apologies.

Comment: thanks for the sample project. But I want to keep the navigation bar on 2nd view controller, not to hide it like that