# Having issues with the navigation bar background color when transferring between 2 VCs

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uinavigationbar

I have a `HomeViewController` which pushes to `SendViewController` and the navigation bar turns from dark blue to white:

In `HomeViewController.swift`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = Styleguide.Colors.darkBlue.color
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = Styleguide.Colors.lightBlue.color
}

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = Styleguide.Colors.darkBlue.color

    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = Styleguide.Colors.darkBlue.color
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = Styleguide.Colors.lightBlue.color
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage() // hides the bottom border
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    ... more 
}
```

In `SendViewController.swift`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillAppear(animated)
   self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .default
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
   self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = .white

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .white
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = Styleguide.Colors.darkBlue.color
    ... more
}
```

Here's the problem:

When popping from `Send` to `Home`, the navigation bar is white and then jumps to be dark blue after animation finishes. (Desired result is an animation from white to dark blue as the pop happens)

Comment: I had a similar problem check out my post, the answers helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44343355/3900902

Comment: check this post may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39835420/navigationbar-delay-updating-bartintcolor-ios10/40255483#40255483

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
 navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = Styleguide.Colors.darkBlue.color
 navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = Styleguide.Colors.lightBlue.color
```

to viewWillDissapear of SendViewController

Comment: I have. It makes no difference. The bar is still white until the pop animation finishes, then jumps to dark blue. Hence my confusion.