# Navigation bar buttons set during viewDidLoad don't appear until after view has appeared in iOS 11

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, ios11

In iOS 10, I could determine the list of navigation bar buttons I want to appear in `viewDidLoad`, and they would appear in the navigation bar as the view controller transitioned in.

In iOS 11, I can no longer do this. Whatever navigation bar buttons were set in interface builder are displayed as the view controller transitions in, and my custom list of buttons are not displayed until after the view finishes sliding in. Updating the buttons in `viewWillAppear` does not help.

Is this simply a bug in iOS 11, or is there something else I should be doing? Is there a workaround so I can continue to display buttons while the screen loads?

In the following example, I have set a button "Default Button" in the storyboard, and override it with an "Edit" button in `viewDidLoad`. The project is [available on Github](https://github.com/clindsay/TestNavigationBarIconsBug).

iOS 10

[image: iOS 10 Behavior]

iOS 11

[image: iOS 11 Behavior]

Comment: Have you checked this on real device?

Comment: Good thought! But yes, I have verified that the same thing happens on a real device.

Comment: Maybe a bug in the split view's detail nested navigation controller, when setting the navigation item properties for some reason don't cause the outermost navigation controller to redraw its navigation bar before the animation begins.

Comment: Loading the view in prepareForSegue in Chris Vasselli's code sample below is a good workaround.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue is that navigation bar icons displayed during the transition appear to be fixed when the view controller is passed off to the navigation controller. By the time that `viewDidLoad` is called, the icons have already been fixed.

In order to fix this, we need to update the navigation bar icons on the view controller's `navigationItem` *before* the view controller is pushed onto the navigation controller stack.

One way to do this would be to setup the navigation bar icons in `awakeFromNib`. This is what @Joe's answer was effectively doing, because apparently `viewDidLoad` is called from `awakeFromNib` when `isViewLoaded` is `true` during `awakeFromNib`.

However, doing this in `awakeFromNib` prevents you from taking into account any properties set on the view controller in `prepareForSegue`. So another option (and the one that I am using) is to force the entire view to load in `prepareForSegue` by adding the line `_ = controller.view` after setting any desired properties.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
            ...
            _ = controller.view
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Move your `Edit` barButton code from `viewDidLoad`  to `isViewLoaded` method as below.

```
  override var isViewLoaded: Bool {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
    return true
  }
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** Above code will fix the transition delay issue. Really, don't have much to explain why this happening. I experienced similar issue in iOS 10 as well [NavigationBar delay updating barTintColor iOS10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39835420/navigationbar-delay-updating-bartintcolor-ios10/40255483#40255483). It could be another bug in `iOS11`.

---

**PS:**

After reading [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/2097563-isviewloaded) about `isViewLoaded` and comparing other view loading methods. Its all about loading `memory` upon view loads.

You don't really need to move you `barButton` code at all.Just implement the `isViewLoaded` method and return to `true` as below:

```
override var isViewLoaded: Bool { return true}
```

Comment: Hmm, very interesting that this works. But overriding `isViewLoaded` to always return true doesn't really seem like a good solution, since it will return `true` when we _haven't_ actually loaded the view yet. And the result of `isViewLoaded` could be used elsewhere, and so overriding it could break something else.

Comment: Did you look at the link (fixed)posted on PS. Apple Doc mentioned clearly `The value of this property is true when the view is in memory or false when it is not`.

Comment: Right. So, by overriding this property we are breaking that behavior, because now the property will be true even before the view is loaded into memory.

Comment: Memory allocation only happen when the view loads. If you wanna go more into it .run a memory test.see is that make any diffrence.